# Why is UITableViewCell not calling didSelectRowAt if, and only if, the tableview has only one row

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` controlled by a `UITableViewController`. When I select a row, I want the `didSelectRowAt` method to call a function to do certain things to the `[String]` object that is the `dataSource`.  It works perfectly, EXCEPT when the `datasource` array has only one item. For example, if the array looks like:

```
var example: [String] = ["What", "Is", "The", "Problem"]
```

I have no problem. I can select any `index` and call the method, the code below will print the `index` and `string` for every index I select including 0.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      print(indexPath.row, example[indexPath.row])
}
```

However, if the array looks like this:

```
var example: [String] = ["What"]
```

The `didSelectRowAt` method doesn't get called at all even though the tableview cell is selectable and shows selection visibly. I built in a button to check the state of the example array and everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

So this is an example of code completion gone wrong. I spent hours chasing it and even rewrote the method a few time but the answer was:

```
didDeselectRowAt
```

Instead of:

```
didSelectRowAt
```

Because it worked after switching cells, very hard to check.

Comment: so many people had this mistake when first time doing tableview / collectionview